# Magento 2 Facing Problem :Could not save product "3194" with position 0 to category 12

Tags: magento2.3, adminhtml, products, category-tree

*I am facing a problem whenever I go into*

> catalog->products->edit product and delete the category from product
>   and click on save button the error is coming. Could not save product
>   "3194" with position 0 to category 12.

***This is happening with my all products.***

*I have searched a lot on this error but could not found a proper solution for that.*

*Please See Image below for more clarity.*

[image]

Comment: Which Magento version you're using?

Comment: @Sumit I am Using 2.3.0

Comment: It is not related to any duplicate URL. The category linking is not happening. Check this file: vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/CategoryLinkRepository.php and check "save" method.

Comment: @RahulAnand so according to you what I understand is the problem is in save method but can you explain a bit more why save method not working? cuz I am new to Magento and going to debug this method as well.